# "Nested" data doesn't show

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to fetch some data from the database. The relationship is many-to-many with one side, of course, being the owning side. Now the problem is, when I enter the default endpoint: http://localhost:8080/api/usluge I get the `"usluge"(engl. services)` i want but even though the "pruzateljiUsluge" field doesn't pop up in the database, that same field is being shown as a response body in my browser through the GET request...Now the problem is this field should not be empty...There are pretty much ALWAYS `pruzateljiUsluge(engl. serviceProviders)`. For example:

The result is get is:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "opisUsluge": "Default usluga description1",
    "pruzateljiUsluge": []
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "opisUsluge": "Default usluga description1",
    "pruzateljiUsluge": []
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "opisUsluge": "Default usluga description3",
    "pruzateljiUsluge": []
}]
```

Whereas the result should be:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "opisUsluge": "Default usluga description1",
    "pruzateljiUsluge": []
},{
    "id": 2,
    "opisUsluge": "Default usluga description1",
    "pruzateljiUsluge": [
           {
                "id": 1,
                "naziv_pruzatelja": "pruzatelj1"
              }{
                "id": 2,
                "naziv_pruzatelja": "pruzatelj2"
              }{
                "id": 3,
                "naziv_pruzatelja": "pruzatelj2"
              }]
},{
    "id": 3,
    "opisUsluge": "Default usluga description3",
    "pruzateljiUsluge":  [
           {
                "id": 3,
                "naziv_pruzatelja": "pruzatelj3"
              },{
                "id": 4,
                "naziv_pruzatelja": "pruzatelj4"
              }]
}]
```

I've tried using `@Transactional`, `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` Hibernate.initialize()..I've tried to force Hibernate to stop closing the session by querying list.size(), but to no avail. The error still persists...

This is my code:

Usluga.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usluga")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Usluga {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "opisUsluge")
    private String opisUsluge;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "pruzateljUsluga",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usluga_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pruzatelj_usluge_id"))
    private Set<PruzateljUsluge> pruzateljiUsluge = new HashSet<>();
}
```

PruzateljUsluge.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pruzateljUsluge")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class PruzateljUsluge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="nazivPruzatelja")
    private String nazivPruzatelja;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "pruzateljiUsluge", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Usluga> usluge = new HashSet<>();
}
```

ServiceMethods.java

```
@Transactional
public List<Usluga> getUslugeMain(){
    List<Usluga> usluge = uslugaRepository.findAll();
    usluge.forEach(usluga -> {
        Hibernate.initialize(usluga.getPruzateljiUsluge().size());
    });
    return usluge;}
```

#EDIT: Does this error have something to do with the fact that the pruzateljUsluga doesn't show up in the database as a field in Usluga table? Or is that irrelevant due to there being a "cross-table" (the table containing the usluga_id and pruzatelj_usluga_id"

#EDIT2: I'm using rest repositories...But theres something weird happening on ˙pruzateljUsluga˙ end...When I call the `localhost:8080/pruzateljUsluga` I get some gibberish:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nazivPruzatelja": "pruzatelj1",
        "usluge": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "opisUsluge": "Default usluga description1",
                "pruzateljiUsluge": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nazivPruzatelja": "pruzatelj2",
        "usluge": [
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nazivPruzatelja": "pruzatelj3",
        "usluge": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "nazivPruzatelja": "pruzatelj4",
        "usluge": []
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "nazivPruzatelja": "pruzatelj5",
        "usluge": []
    }
]
```

Where my database association table looks like this:

```
usluga_id    :    pruzatelj_usluge_id
    2                    1
    2                    2
    2                    3
    3                    3
    3                    4
```

So basically this is OK...Just when I fetch the data, nothing is displayed properly...

#EDIT3:

Here is the code for adding pretty much everything:

```
public void addNewUsluga(Usluga usluga) {
        try {
            Usluga newUsluga = new Usluga();
            newUsluga.setOpisUsluge(usluga.getOpisUsluge());

            List<Long> pruzateljUslugeIds = usluga.getPruzateljiUsluge().stream()
                    .map(PruzateljUsluge::getId)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            List<PruzateljUsluge> pruzateljiUslugeEntities = pruzateljUslugaRepository.findAllById(pruzateljUslugeIds);

            newUsluga.getPruzateljiUsluge().addAll(pruzateljiUslugeEntities);

            uslugaRepository.save(newUsluga);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while adding new usluga: " + e.getMessage());
        }
}

public void addNewPruzatelj(PruzateljUsluge pruzateljUsluge) {
        try {
            PruzateljUsluge noviPruzatelj = new PruzateljUsluge();
            noviPruzatelj.setNazivPruzatelja(pruzateljUsluge.getNazivPruzatelja());
            pruzateljUslugaRepository.save(noviPruzatelj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while adding new PruzateljUsluge: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

#EDIT 4: Added `@JsonIdentityInfo` in the `Usluga.java` and `PruzateljUsluge.java`: `service.java` and `serviceProvider.java` respectively.

Comment: How are you saving the "nested data"? E.g. If you want to add a new `PruzateljUsluge` with multiple `Usluga's`, are all the `Usluga's` you're adding already saved to the database? If they're not, that might be why the `pruzateljUsluga` doesn't show

Comment: Also, the code you posted seems like it would give an infinite recursion error because there's no `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` (or `@JsonIgnore`)

Comment: For my problem I'm trying to add a new `Usluga` with multiple `PruzateljUsluge` not the other way around. And yea, when I'm adding a new `Usluga` with multiple `PruzateljUsluge` all of the `PruzateljUsluge` ALREADY EXIST. So there should be no problem for them not showing. In regards to your second comment, you are right, there would be an infinite recursion error...I did not include any of those annotations. @FakeIfe

Comment: Hm, looks fine to me, no clue why they not appear. Regarding your edit: no, n-m does only require id-fields in owning and non-owning table. Have you concidered using spring-data-rest-repositories?

Comment: The code when I add something is in the post under the #EDIT 3

Comment: Regarding EDIT2: Here you got your n-m relations! So your owning-entity does not represent n-m well but your non-owning entity represent n-m very well. Weird! Hm, the entity is called Uslug*a*, the rest-repository is called /Uslug*e* (**e** at the end), Maybe we look at a different entity?

Comment: @Grim...Actually, no...No owning entity is being represented well at all. The owning entity is missing the non-owning entities, and the non-owning entities are wrongly displaying owning entities. And again...Why is non-owning side `pruzateljUsluge` displaying (even though it's wrong) displaying anything while the owning side `Usluga` not displaying anything

Comment: @AntiFalx Why do you think `pruzateljUsluga` is represented wrong? The array-of-numbers is a array of indexes, not a array of primary-keys AFAIK.

Comment: Well, because, at least for me, under the id:1 of `pruzateljUsluga` there is a full `Usluga` object, whereas under the id:2 there is only an id of a `Usluga` object